# Unique Authentication for React App to Spring boot thymeleaf app

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

We have two web application 
 1. written in react.js and it's backend API written using spring boot + spring security. 
 2. Another web application written using spring boot + spring security
    + thymeleaf template.

Both the application we called as react app and thymleaf app.

I wanted redirection for authenticated user from react app to thymleaf app but by using same auth token, react app currently passing auth token in header for each request.

How to do you pass to thymlead app view request same auth token from react app to thymleaf app, how this integration will happen seamless.

In thymlead app following code Request End points are there

```
@RequestMapping("/select/test/method")
    public String selectDepositMethod(Model model, Authentication authentication) {
        model.addAttribute("name", "Select test method");

        return "deposit/select-test-method";
    }
```

Wanted to redirect from react app to thymleaf app to above end points.

What are the changes we need to on react app or thymeleaf app.

Can you please suggest the appropriate changes to us, Your help is appreciate to us.

Answer (score 0):

Recommend you checkout Spring Session. See this article:

https://drissamri.be/blog/2015/05/21/spring-security-and-spring-session/